# Getting a map from Firestore and setting it to a new map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two methods the first one for getting a map stored in Firestore

```
Future daysMap(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode, int totalDays) async {
  await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages')
      .document(packageCode)
      .get().then((doc){
       // print(doc.data['DaysMap']);

        return doc.data['DaysMap'];
  });
}
```

It works correctly and prints out the map. The second method is for setting the map from Firestore to a new map in order to loop on it.

```
currentWorkout(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode,totalDays) async {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> days = await daysMap(user, packageCode, totalDays);
  print(days);
}
```

When i print our the new map 'days' it always prints null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **async/await** style.

```
Future daysMap(FirebaseUser user, String packageCode, int totalDays) async {
 DocumentSnapshot doc =  await users.document(user.uid).collection('myPackages').document(packageCode).get();

 return doc.data['DaysMap'];

}
```